# Is $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=0$ if $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, derivatives, proof-verification

Let $f$ is continuously differentiable positive function, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0$, and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'(x)$ exist, is it true that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=0$.

My answer was yes, and this is my "proof".

Since the limit of $f'(x)$ exists, we can conclude that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'(x)=0$. Suppose that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}>0$. Hence, there are $c,k\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that for every $x>k$, we have $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}>c$, or $f'(x)>cf(x)$. By letting $x\rightarrow\infty$, we shall get $0>0$, which is a contradiction.

However, my Sensei told me that this proof is wrong, but he didn't tell me which part. He just gave me a counter example that if $f=\phi$ (pdf of standard normal distribution), then we shall get the limit is infinity.

So, my questions are:

1. which part of my proof is wrong?
2. to make the conclusion true (the limit of such fraction is $0$), is there any additional premise I need?
3. how about $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{[f'(x)]^2}{F(x)}$, where $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$? (I think if I can solve the problem of the second question, I'll get some ideas for the third)

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: There is one fundamental problem apart from those mentioned in various answers. How do you know that limit of $f'/f$ exists? If numerator and denominator both tends to $0$ then the ratio can show all kinds of limiting behavior including oscillation and infinities.

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem when you write that “By letting $x\to\infty$, we shall get $0>0$”. No! The only conclusion that you reach here is that $0\geqslant0$. Therefore, there is no contradiction.

Comment: thank you so much all, but how about the other questions?

Answer (score 3):

Your conclusion $f'(x) > c f(x) $ implies $0 \gt 0$ (when $x \to \infty$ is wrong.

If $f'(x) > cf(x) $ this implies that when we take $x \to \infty$ then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) \ge c \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$.

Comment: thank you so much all, I realized my mistake, but how about the other questions?

Comment: @RizkyRezaFujisaki you can take $f(x) = e \ ^ {-x}$ , so $f>0$ , $lim f(x) = 0$ . but $lim \dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = lim \dfrac{- e \ ^ {-x}}{e \ ^ {-x}} = lim -1 = -1 \ne 0$ so the statement is false.

Answer (score 3):

- With stronger hypothesis (like $f>0$), your problem is equivalent to $$\lim_{x\to \infty }g(x)=-\infty \implies \lim_{x\to \infty }g'(x)=0,$$
  which is of course wrong.
- But with simple intuition, if $\lim_{x\to \infty }f'(x)$ exist and is not $0$, then it's bounded at $+\infty $, and since $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)=0$, you either have that $\lim_{x\to \infty }\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\pm\infty $ or doesn't exist.
- For a counter example, take $f(x)=e^{-x}$.

Comment: Presumably you're making the substitution $g(x) = \log f(x)$; it's worth at least mentioning that!

Answer (score 0):

> which part of my proof is wrong?

Let's plug in the counterexample you were given and find out. Letting $f(x) = \exp(-x^2/2)/\sqrt{2\pi}$,

- $ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'(x)=0 $
- $ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f'(x)/f(x) = -\infty$

So we already see a gap in your proof: you completely forgot to consider the case that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)/f(x) < 0$.